# Dynamically create Javascript Object from String and put object as parameters of function

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I would like to create Javascript object from Javascript String.

```
var arrayOfName = new Array();
arrayOfName.push("module1");
arrayOfName.push("module2");
arrayOfName.push("module3");
arrayOfName.push("module4");
```

For this example, i would like to create 4 objects : module1, module2, module3 and module4.

And after, how can i passed these object as a parameters of a function ? like this :

```
this.myFunctionTest = function myFunctionTest(module1, module2, module3, module4) {
  // ...
}
```

Ideally, the code must work for all elements which are in the Javascript Array called "arrayOfName".

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) like this

```
myFunctionTest.apply(this, arrayOfName);
```

The `apply` function passes all the elements of `arrayOfName` as parameters to `myFunctionTest`.

As the number of parameters grow in number, you may not want to or find it difficult to maintain the number or parameters. Don't worry, JavaScript has got that covered :) It has something called [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) which is an array like object. You can access the first parameter with `arguments[0]`, like accessing a normal array object.

```
var arrayOfName = [];
arrayOfName.push("module1");
arrayOfName.push("module2");
arrayOfName.push("module3");
arrayOfName.push("module4");

function myFunctionTest(param1, param2, param3) {
    console.log(param1, param2, param3);
    console.log(arguments);
}

myFunctionTest.apply(this, arrayOfName);
// module1 module2 module3
// { '0': 'module1', '1': 'module2', '2': 'module3', '3': 'module4' }
```

If you want to require node modules, with this method

```
var modules = ["lodash", "underscore", "q"];
require.apply(this, modules);
```

But if you want to get the objects returned by the `require` for each of the modules, then your best bet would be using `Array.prototype.map` with `require`, like this

```
console.log(modules.map(require));
```

If you have a function like this

```
function modules(module1, module2, ...) {
    ...
}
```

And if you want to invoke it with all the loaded modules, then you would do something like this

```
modules.apply(this, modules.map(require));
```

Comment: Is this will work if i want to pass as parameter of require ? Like `require(arrayOfPath, function(arrayOfName) {})`

Comment: @wawanopoulos You mean, you want to `require` multiple modules at once?

Comment: To be more compleete, i have some string in entry representing module name. After, i must do an internal search to find the correct path of each module, and after genereate some object to pass in function parameter of require. At the end, i would like to have something like this : `require(["../path/module1", "../path/module2"], function(module1, module2) { .....} `

Answer (score 1):

Using  `.apply` function of Function prototype

```
myFunctionTest.apply(this, arrayOfName);
```

Note: You can find more here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: Is this will work if i want to pass as parameter of require ? Like `require(arrayOfPath, function(arrayOfName) {})`

Comment: Can you explain it more ? Answer is yes, but I'm confused with names of variables and from what framewrok it is